# How does a resolver know a DNS response is authoritative?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

The title says everything about me question. How does a resolver know the response comes from an authoritative name server? An equivalent question: what flag or field is marked by a name server to say to the resolver that its response wasn't authoritative? And last related question, secondary DNS servers are always non-authoritative?

Comment: What do you mean by "secondary DNS servers"? If you mean servers with slave zones, those will answer authoritatively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DNS Response message header contains a bit indicating whether the resolved name came from an authoritative server, this would be the field called **AA** in the header reference table listed below:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      ID                       | 
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    QDCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ANCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    NSCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ARCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

See [RFC 1035 §4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4.1.1) for header format details